# Grammar of past events

Tags: grammar, simple-past, descriptive-grammar

How is it grammatically correct to say "Did you hear what I just said?"?. Is it also possible to say something as "Did you hear what i say?"?. I mean, that direct following the past simple grammar incline me to the second option, but  I tend to use the first one by intuition,  because two parts of the question look very "separate".

Could someone explain this on solid  grounds? Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Did you hear what I'm saying* is idiomatic. English doesn't use the simple present for the same thing most languages use it for, so *Did you hear what I say* doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterShor, thank you for a very clear explanation!

Comment: @PeterShor  And a one tiny additional question:  " Did you hear what I'm saying"  and "Do you hear what I'm saying" , aren't they both correct and have almost the same meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so much of English, what you say here is determined not strictly by grammar but by idiom and usage.

***Did you hear what I just said?*** is idiomatic, and depending on tone of voice could be made to sound perfectly polite. But it has the potential to be brusque and offensive, if said without care.

***Did you hear what I say?*** is neither grammatical, nor idiomatic. But you could say ***Do you hear what I say?***, but this will almost always sound impolite.

Both of the above could carry the implication that the person was not listening when they should have been.

If you are genuinely concerned as to whether someone heard you or not, more politely you might say ***Could you hear me just now?***, or even ***Could you hear what I said just now?***

**If your concerns are wider than this, involving use of different tenses in the same sentence - please elaborate. But there are many previous questions on the site about that.**

Comment: *Could you hear me just now?* seems much more idiomatic than *Could you hear what I said just now?*

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I will amend.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I was a bit confused by the usage of tenses here, but I hope that now I got the point. I saw a few similar questions here but didn't  manage to  find exactly the same, I would look more attentively the next time.